# How to distribute requests to pods on a Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service and 4 pods which wordpress installed on each. This is my service configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 31001
    nodePort: 31001
    targetPort: apache
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  type: NodePort
```

Now all traffic are distributed randomly by the service. I want to change it that work non-random (I think It's name was `round robin`).
I have read [the official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) but I don't understand it.

Is there any way to manage traffic respectively?
Could anybody please show me an example?

Comment: Hi, what alternative approach you want to have?  There is a field called `session affinity` which makes it possible to choose a fixed pod based on session. Here is the command for further read `kubectl explain svc.spec.sessionAffinity`

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Actually I only want send requests from the service equally between pods. For example if I have 100 requests, every pod will give 25 requests.

Comment: There are lots of ways of defining "equally". It could mean that the request distributor keeps track of the 4 services and distributes requests to service 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4, etc. That's round robin. Another way of defining equally is where service 4 is on a slow node, so it can process only half as many requests as services 1,2,3. So a distributor would do 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3, etc. Another way recognizes that requests come from users and have session state, so requests from user 1 always have to go to their session on service 3. Can you clarify?

Comment: In general, however, k8s Services do not offer intelligent traffic distribution, and only support round robin. To use other techniques- weighting, affinity, retries- you need to use an Ingress resource instead.

Comment: @JonahBenton Thank you for replies.  First solution in your first comment is what i want. But It is a little different. I have only 1 service and 4 pods and I'd like to know how to distribute requests from my service to my pods so that every pod receive similar requests.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar", and how do you see the distinction between "random" and "round robin" in your question? By default a Kubernetes Service does what it sounds like you want, but there was some concern about it? And apologies, in my comment my use of "service" was short for "microservice" not "k8s service" and can be read as "pod."

Comment: @JonahBenton If Kubernetes service distributes request to pods "round robin" not "random" by default, It will be what I want. by "similar" i mean that every pod get same number of request. i.e if i have 8 requests and 4 pods each pod gets two requests

Comment: Ok, yes, at a high level, k8s services distribute requests to backing pods by round robin. There are more details behind that, and a number of reasons that request counts per pod will never be exactly equal, but high level/common case, it's round robin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Meysam mentioned, Kubernetes service distributes the request to pods using "round robin" technology by default.

I would advise you (and all who will read this topic in the future) to read more information about [Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and [How does kubernetes handle load balancing](http://blog.wercker.com/how-does-kubernetes-handle-load-balancing). It will shed a light on tons of questions.

> Kubernetes uses a feature called kube-proxy to handle the virtual IPs for services. Kubernetes allocates tasks to pods within a service by the round-robin method
>
> With round-robin allocation, the system maintains a list of destinations. When a request comes in, it assigns the request to the next destination on the list, then permutes the list (either by simple rotation, or a more complex method), so the next request goes to the following destination on the list.

Comment: What is the right way to balance requests based on least CPU utilized pod?