# How to distribute number of requests equally to pod replicas in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using kubernetes, RKE2 with 3 master nodes and 10 workers.
In my implementation, I have an API route that does a calculation that takes 3 minutes.
It turns out that the more times I call this route in parallel, the longer it takes for me to get the answers. Sometimes it takes even longer than calling the routes serially.
From what I've observed, the distribution of requests across pods is not uniform. If I make 20 requests and have 20 service pods, only 6 or 7 pods are used, with some pods receiving 2, 3 or even 4 requests.
Evidently, the pods that receive 3 and 4 requests, spend much more time to return the answers.
This link
[How to distribute requests to pods on a Kubernetes service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453918/how-to-distribute-requests-to-pods-on-a-kubernetes-service)
clarified the question of how load balancing should be and what is round robin, but apparently my cluster is not behaving as it should.
As I understand it, the default behavior with 20 pods and 20 practically simultaneous requests should be 1 request for each pod.
I've been trying to treat this problem for weeks, without success. I hope someone with more experience in kubernetes can help me and others in the community who have this same problem.

Follows deployment yaml on kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: alignment-pvc
  namespace: development
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
  volumeName: alignment-pv-dev
  storageClassName: longhorn-static
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alignment-deployment
  namespace: development
  labels:
    version: v1
    app: alignment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alignment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: alignment
    spec:
      nodeName: m21429.contaboserver.net
      containers:
        - image: joaollr/alignment:75819c1d8168f5187165d9f79a1af8cde27b47d4
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: alignment
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: core-config
          resources: 
            requests:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "0.2" 
            limits:
              memory: "15Gi"  
              cpu: "4"  
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: alignment-pvc
            - mountPath: /raster
              name: raster-pvc
            - mountPath: /vector
              name: vector-pvc
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: alignment-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: alignment-pvc
        - name: raster-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: raster-pvc
            readOnly: true
        - name: vector-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: vector-pvc
            readOnly: true
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: alignment-service
  namespace: development
  labels:
    app: alignment
    service: alignment
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8000 
  selector:
    app: alignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes service distribution is (normally) performed by `kube-proxy`. The `kube-proxy` has 2 "modes": iptables and ipvs. "iptables" is the default and uses random distribution. "ipvs" must be explicitly selected and uses round-robin (rr) by default.

So, first try to switch to proxy-mode=ipvs. But...

It is not that simple since the kube-proxy instances on each node works independently. This means that a request that is distributed on node A, may pick the same target as a request distributed on node B. So you will only get perfect round-robin if all requests are distributed on the same node. That may be the case if you traffic comes from an external source and enters on *one* node (i.e. no ECMP).

Some CNI-plugins, like Cilium or Antrea, has options to bypass the `kube-proxy` and do service distribution in their own way. You should check if that is the case in your system.